# Let $S= \{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 \mid a,b,c,d \in \Bbb N\}$. Show that $|S|=|\Bbb N|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S= \{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 \mid a,b,c,d \in \Bbb N\}$. Show that the cardinality of $|S|=|\Bbb N|$ by applying the Cantor-Schroder Bernstein Theorem; that is, by constructing the injective function from $S$ to $\Bbb N$ and vice versa, and then conclude that there is a bijective function from $S$ to $\Bbb N$.

**Here, $\Bbb N$ is the of all positive integers.**

**Attempt:**

First, let's construct an injective function from $S$ to $\Bbb N$. We can represent any element of $S$ as a sum of four squares: $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$. We will map this element to a unique positive integer using a pairing function.

We can use the following pairing function to map four positive integers $(a, b, c, d)$ to a unique positive integer:
$$f(a, b, c, d) = 2^a3^b5^c7^d.$$

This function assigns a unique prime factor to each variable, ensuring that no two distinct combinations of $(a, b, c, d)$ will produce the same result. Since the prime factorization of positive integers is unique, the function $f$ is injective.

Now, let's construct an injective function from $\Bbb N$ to $S$. We can map a positive integer $n$ to a unique element of $S$ by expressing it as a sum of four squares. This can be done using a method known as Lagrange's four-square theorem.

Lagrange's four-square theorem states that any positive integer can be represented as the sum of four squares. We can use this theorem to find four positive integers $(a, b, c, d)$ such that $n = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$. Since $n$ is a positive integer, we are guaranteed to find such a representation.

Therefore, we can define a function $g(n) = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$, where $(a, b, c, d)$ is the representation of $n$ as the sum of four squares. This function maps a positive integer $n$ to a unique element of $S$, and thus is injective.

By constructing an injective function from $S$ to $\Bbb N$, i.e. the mapping $f$, and another injective function from $\Bbb N$ to $S$, i.e. the mapping $g$, we have satisfied the conditions of the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem.
Therefore, there exists a bijective function between $S$ and $\Bbb N$.

Hence, $|S| = |\Bbb N|$.

Does this approach correct?
Many thanks in advanced.

Comment: Directly quoting Lagrange's four-square Theorem may be trivialising the question...I'm not sure.

Comment: And I think adding a ton of function stuff seems a bit redundant here. We can just prove that $\forall x\in S, x\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\forall x\in\mathbb{N}, x\in S$.

Comment: Your $f$ isn't a function. For example, is $f(7)$ equal to $420$, $630$, $1050$ or $1470$? And yes, Lagrange's four-square theorem just says $S = \mathbb N$, so you if you have it you don't need anything else - however $|S| = |\mathbb N|$ is much simpler than Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: $S$ is a subset of the natural numbers, so we already have that injection.  If you meant for $S$ to be the set of $4-$ tuples of natural numbers, that would be different.  But $(2, 1, 1, 1)$ and $(1,2,1,1)$ define the same element of $S$, and so on.

Comment: @lulu $S$ is a subset of $\Bbb N$ and then there is injection. What's the explicit function of this injection?

Comment: Well, since $S\subset \mathbb{N}$ , $f(n)=n$ is an injection from $S$ to $\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: The identity map is an injection.

Comment: Here, $n$ is $n=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ for some $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb N$?

Comment: To stress, the function you provide is not even a function from $S\to \mathbb N$.  An element of $S$ is an integer, not a $4-$tuple.    Your argument works if you had $\mathbb N^4$ instead of $S$.

Comment: And then for the vice versa, what's the explicit function?

Comment: @lulu Okay, got it now. Thanks!

Comment: Just about anything you think of works.  For $n\in \mathbb N$ define $F(n)=n^2+1^2+1^2+1^2=n^2+3$ for example.  I am assuming that you aren't allowing $0$ as a natural number...if you do allow $0$, just take $F(n)=n^2$.

Comment: Should note:  If you want to invoke Lagrange (definitely overkill here) then you *must* allow $0\in \mathbb N$.  Obviously $1$ isn't the sum of the squares of four positive integers. Neither is $6$.