# Let $S=\{x \in \Bbb N \mid x=a^2+b^2 \text{ for some $a,b \in \Bbb N$}\}. $ Show that $|S| = |\mathbb{N}|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let
$S=\{x \in \Bbb N \mid x=a^2+b^2 \text{ for some $a,b \in \Bbb N$}\}.
$

Show that $|S| = |\mathbb{N}|$.

How to construct explicitly the bijection from $S$ to $\Bbb N$? Does the map $f(n)=n^2+1$ work?

Any ideas? Many thanks in advanced.

Comment: Isn't this like a famous conjecture? Can't remember the name but I've seen it somewhere.

Comment: See [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)

Comment: This is very similar to [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4718031/let-s-a2b2c2d2-mid-a-b-c-d-in-bbb-n-show-that-s-bbb-n)...it should be easy for you to use the same techniques to show that a bijection exists.  Writing an explicit bijection seems tedious...are you sure you want one?

Comment: Can you prove there are infinitely many primes of the form $4k+1$?

Comment: @lulu Yeah I know. But, I really want to know the explicit bijection if any.

Comment: I think you will find it extremely difficult to write one down.  As you should be aware, you are, essentially, asking for a simple rule for finding the $n^{th}$ natural number the prime factorization of which contains primes of the form $4k+3$ only to even powers.

Comment: You need no concrete bijection to determine the cardinality. Since the set is obviously a subset of the natural numbers , it must be countable. So it is enough to establish that it is an infinite set.